# How to extract html links with a matching word

Tags: html, web-crawler

I am trying to make a crawler that can use a text file list of urls be turned auto assigned as variables to later be added into a list that can be parsed to search for urls containing the word "wp- ". Unfortunately, I am getting stuck at the part where I need to scrape the page to see if any urls bring up " wp- ". I've tried a number of ways but nothing is working. I've tried various semblances of

> //a[contains(@href, 'wp-')]

but it does not work. Any suggestions on how to get the parsing for wp- working?

Here is my code so far

'''

```
#!/usr/#!/usr/bin/python

import urllib.request
import urlopen

# import urls into readable python file
f = open("url-list.txt", "r")
text = f.read()


# turn urls in file into a list by spliting it into lines
text_list = text.splitlines()
f.close()
#print(text_list)  #dont need to show the links as list


#make list into variables
count = 0
for breakaway in text_list: #made iterate of a list to set their value
    count = count + 1
    print(count + 0, " Sending url-list to scraper...")

for url in //a[contains(@href, 'wp-')].extract():
print(url)
'''
```